# Почему программа ничего не выводит?

Tags: c++

Я осуществляю поиск простых чисел решетом Эратосфена. `n` - верхний порог, т.е. до какого числа искать. Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = pow(10, 7);

    bool bools[n+1];
    vector<int> primes;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        bools[i] = true;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int k = 2;

        while ( (i * k) <= n )
        {
            bools[i * k] = false;
            k++;
        }

        if ( bools[i] != false )
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
        cout << primes[i] << endl;

}
```

Для n = 10^6 всё печатает меньше, чем за секунду. Но вот для n = 10^7 программа вообще ничего не печатает и через несколько секунд после запуска завершается.

Проблема в типе данных? Я пробовал их менять, но эта замена не изменила результата. Что делать?

Comment: Думаю, 10 мегабайт массива `bools` просто не помещаются в стеке...

Comment: @Harry , понял. Я изменил ```bools``` на вектор и всё вывело. А вообще, если бы нужно было бы обходиться без вектора, как решить проблему?

Comment: В C/C++ нельзя считать что стек резиновый. Все большие структуры должны быть в куче. То есть, или vector или new bool[n]/malloc.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну можно было и глобальную переменную завести в данном случае.

Comment: А решето написано так себе.